# Простая ошибка и калькулятор

Tags: php, html

нужно сделать простой калькулятор по примеру учителя,сверил свой код и учителя больше 10 раз и не нашел ошибку.
Вроде как ошибка в переменной $output .
Сам я в php полный ноль.

[Калькулятор](https://smash2ten.000webhostapp.com)

```html
<html>
<head>

 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>



<?php





/*КАЛЬКУЛЯТОР*/




if(
    isset($_POST['num1']) && is_numeric ($_POST['num1']) &&
    isset($_POST['num2']) && is_numeric ($_POST['num2']) &&
    isset($_POST['operator']) && !empty ($_POST['operator'])
    
)

{
    $num1=$_POST['num1']*1;
    $num2=$_POST['num2']*1;
    $operator=$_POST['operator'];


    $output ="$num1 $operator $num2 = ";
    switch ($operator){
        case '+':
        $output .=$num1 + $num2;break;
        case '-':
        $output .=$num1 - $num2;break;
        case '*':
        $output .=$num1 * $num2;break;
        case '/':
    $output .=$num1 / $num2;break;
       if ($num1 = 0){
            echo "Нельзя делить на ноль";
            break;
        }break;
    
    break;
 default:
    $output="Неизвестный оператор '$operator'";
    
}

}




 ?>


 <style>
.calc{
    text-align:center;
    
}

    table,th,td{
        border:2px solid #000;
        border-collapse: collapse;  
        margin:50px auto;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    th{
      
      
    }

    </style>

    

<div class="calc">
    <h1>Каклькулятор</h1>

    <?php 

if(isset ($output)){
    print "<p>Результат:$output</p>";
}

?>




<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" menthod="post">
<p>Число 1</p>
<input type="text" name="num1">
<P>Оператор:</P>
<input type="text" name="operator">
<P>Число 2</P>
<input type="text" name="num2"> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Cчитать!">
</form>



</div>








</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Каклькулятор` особенно порадовал))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что ошибка в этой строчке:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" menthod="post">
```

У вас атрибут называется *me**n**thod*, а вы, конечно, имели в виду *method*, поэтому браузер отправляет запрос как GET, следовательно, в массив `$_POST` ничего не попадает.

Кроме того, вот в этом фрагменте

```
case '/':
$output .=$num1 / $num2;break;
   if ($num1 = 0){
        echo "Нельзя делить на ноль";
        break;
    }break;
```

куча ошибок: вы сначала делите, а потом проверяете (для сравнения используется `==`), да еще и не тот операнд (нужно проверять делитель, а не делимое); более того, сравнение бессмысленно, так как будет совершен выход из `switch` раньше времени из-за лишнего `break`. То есть:

```
case '/':
   if ($num1 == 0)                         // Если делитель равен нулю
        $output = "Нельзя делить на ноль"; // то сохраняем в output сообщение
   else
        $output .= $num1 / $num2;          // иначе производим деление
   break;
```

Comment: Благодарю,проверял я только php код.